# Jasmine testing and html reporter

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Im starting my adventure with Jasmine and I want to turn off html reporter, but I dont know how. I only need that some var will be true or false after testing like

```
var testResult = expect(true).toBe(true);
console.log(testResult); // true;
```

but jasmine always is adding me reporter like this http://branchandbound.net/pics/jasmine-html.png

Can any one help me?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can run jasmine headlessly?  How to do it will depend on your development stack. What are you using?

Comment: this is my homework, I need to make some live editor with task to do with javascript, and I want to use jasmine to check if it OK or BAD solution but I dont want this reporter

Comment: Is the code you are testing running in the browser, is there a server side component?

Comment: testing will be running in the browser

Comment: I need to do something like this: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/2/section/1/using-filters